# Month wise sum of column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i am using php and mysql.I have one table with one column as recdatetime as datetime datatype .

If i search record between two months i want sum of quantity column of same table.

If i have following record.

```
quantity recdatetime
**44** `2014-01-01 16:53:06`
**14** ` 2014-01-21 16:53:06`
**10** `2013-12-21 16:53:06 `
**17** `2013-12-22 16:53:06 `
**29** `2013-11-20 16:53:06`
```

---

If i search between November 2013 and January 2014  i want output in following manner.

```
November December January    
29        27       58
```

I want Mysql query for above output.

Comment: Your problem needs to be broken into two problems.  The first is how to summarize by month, and the second is how to pivot your table to make the month rows into columns. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Start with this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS s, DATE_FORMAT(recdatetime, '%M') AS m
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(recdatetime, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: @Moeez: you forgot GROUP BY. Btw there are already legit answers there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use month(recdatetime), sum(quantity) and group by month(recdatetime).

```
Select year(recdatetime), month(recdatetime), sum(quantity) as total from x
group by year(recdatetime),month(recdatetime);
```

You will need the year or it will also sum up months for different years. You normaly do not want this. And add a where condition to only get the months you want. Hope you can do that on your own.

Switching rows and columns could be done in the output.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
select sum(quantity) as sumQty,recdatetime FROM table_name group by Month(recdatetime
```